# Determining if this is the first time servlet has run

Tags: java, servlets

Is there a way to *properly* tell if "this is the very first time" a servlet has run once an app starts? I'm currently using a request parameter, detecting if it's null, and if so running logic that's needed only the first time through.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A request parameter is pretty clumsy. It's also spoofable. A class variable is also not useful if you have multiple servlets. I'd rather set an attribute in the [`ServletContext`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html). Maybe in a [`Filter`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/Filter.html), depending on the functional requirement.

```
if (servletContext.getAttribute("firstTime") == null) {
    servletContext.setAttribute("firstTime", true);
    // Do your first-time stuff here.
}
```

I am however curious about the functional requirement behind for which you think that this is the solution. Is it to do some initialization stuff on webapp's startup irrespective of the servlet used and you don't need the `HttpServletRequest`/`HttpServletResponse` at all, for example? For that a [`ServletContextListener`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletContextListener.html) would be a much better solution. It provides methods to hook on webapp's startup and shutdown.

```
@WebListener
public class Config implements ServletContextListener {

    @Override 
    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent event) {
        // Do stuff during webapp's startup.
    }

    @Override 
    public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent event) {
        // Do stuff during webapp's shutdown.
    }

}
```

Comment: Yes it is to do some initialization stuff on startup irrespective of the servlet used. I'll try this ServletContextListener....

Comment: Yes, I already expected that :) Just `@Override` the `contextInitialized()` method and do the desired job in there. You may find some useful examples in [those answers](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A157882+%22implements+servletcontextlistener%22).

Answer (score 3):

What's wrong with the init() method?

Comment: I don't know? Is that a good way to initial stuff on startup? If so, must I override it?

Comment: @robert: So you didn't know about that method at all? Well, whether to use it depends on the sole functional requirement which is yet still unclear. If the initialization is *specific* to the servlet, then yes, the `init()` is way to go.

Comment: @robertlewis: of course it is, that's what it is *for.* And of course you must override it, otherwise where are you going to put the code?

Answer (score 1):

"The first time" is a fuzzy concept; what does it mean on multiplexed servers, for example? You first need to decide what this means, exactly.